# How do i only accept string values in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, numbers

I am trying to create a script in Matlab that when called it will tell you if you have entered a letter of the alphabet and if the user does not enter a character value like a number value the function will tell the user that the value entered is not a letter of the alphabet.
The code I have so far:

```
x= input('Enter a value: ','s');
if (x>= -1000000 && x<=100000)
    fprintf('You have entered "%s" which is not a letter of the alphabet\n',x)
else 
    fprintf('You have entered "%s" which is a letter in the alphabet\n',x)
end
```

I know I am probably coding this way wrong but any help at all would be greatly appreciated. I am fairly new at Matlab but have some experience in C programming. In my script's if statement i tried to make the script print the first statement when the user entered a number between a large set of numbers, and print the second print statement if the user entered a value not in the set of numbers (characters or 'string values').

Comment: What you need to do is something along the lines of determining if the input is a character, and that the length is 1. Try something like `length(x) == 1 && isletter(x)`. Also note the order here matters.

Comment: You may want to look at the documentation for [`ischar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ischar.html) and [`isnumeric`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnumeric.html)

Comment: @darthbith I used `ischar` initially but if the user passes a string containing a number like `'1'` then `ischar` will return true as well. I think he needs `isletter` and then also making sure the input is of length 1 before calling it, since `isletter` returns a vector.

Comment: @jucestain Good point, here's the documentation for [`isletter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isletter.html). I don't think you need the length check because if any of the values in the returned vector are false, the evaluation will turn out false, so it will be clear that a number was entered somewhere in the input. Anyways, the OP did not give enough information for us to judge that...

Comment: @darthbith Yes, OP was unclear... I assumed he meant a single character input